# recursive PHP function to retrive all the children for the specified category

Tags: php

I would like to write a recursive PHP function to retrive all the children for the specified category. I tried the one described here, but it didn't output what I have expected.

My categories table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `category_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_slug` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_parent` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `category_description_ro` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_description_en` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Bellow is an example of data in the table:

```
category id | category name | category_parent

1            Categoria 1            0        
2            Categoria 2            0        
3            Categoria 3            0        
4            Categoria 1.1          1        
5            Categoria 1.2          1        
6            Categoria 1.3          1        
7            Categoria 1.1.2        4
```

I want to know how I print this recursively in PHP.

Comment: Oh no, code rampage! It's on the loose! Oh the humanity! Please wrap your MySQL (and any other code) in a `code` block.

Comment: You tried the one described here? Where?

Comment: @rdlowrey No, `<code>` is discouraged. Simply click the `{ }` icon in the menu to format text as code - that will also allow for proper indentation, syntax highlighting and linebreaks.

Comment: i'm confused about the numbers at the end of Categoria. Is the name of category 1 called "Categoria" or "Categoria 1"? Also, you have 1.1.2 4 at the end of the last category? Is the name of it Categoria 1 and that parent categories are 1, 2 and 4? This is very confusing.

Comment: do you have to stick to the table you have above? also in you data id 4 is parent of id 7?

Comment: @bowlerae, @Elen, his design isn't that weird in my opinion. `category_parent` denotes which supercategory that tuple belongs to. Not the other way around.

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847365/convert-my-database-table-to-a-tree-and-get-leaf-nodes-in-php/8848070#8848070

Comment: The formatting is better now, I didn't know if the parent category was 1.1.2 4 or what. And I couldn't reformat because I didn't know what it was supposed to be.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen That's what I was getting at -- I didn't mean a `<code>` block or I would have said a `<code>` **tag**. I should have been more clear.

Comment: @jeetu from your question and the answers it looks like that it has been answered. Please accept one of the answers that did it for you as the answer or make more clear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

```
<?php    
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");

// Builds the array lists with data from the categories table
while ($items = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $categories['items'][$items['category_id']] = $items;
    $categories['parents'][$items['category_parent']][] = $items['category_id'];
}    

//the function
function category_tree($parent, $array)
{
   $return = "";

   if (isset($array['parents'][$parent]))
   {
      $return .= "<ul>";

       foreach ($array['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
       {
          if(!isset($array['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $return .= "<li>".$array['items'][$itemId]['category_name']."</li> \n";
          }

          if(isset($array['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $return .= "<li>".$array['items'][$itemId]['category_name'];
             $return .= category_tree($itemId, $array);
             $return .= "</li>";
          }
       }
       $return .= "</ul>";
   }

   return $return;
}


echo category_tree(0, $categories);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data has been initialized to an array `$data`.

```
$data = array(array("1", "Categoria 1", "0"),
        array("2", "Categoria 2", "0"),
        array("3", "Categoria 3", "0"),
        array("4", "Categoria 1.1", "1"),
        array("5", "Categoria 1.2", "1"),
        array("6", "Categoria 1.3", "1"),
        array("7", "Categoria 1.1.2", "4"));
```

You can use the following

```
function build_tree($data, $cat=0, $indent=0)
{
    $out = "";
    foreach($data as $entry)
    {
        if ($entry[2] != $cat)
            continue;

        $padding = str_repeat(' ',$indent);
        $out .= sprintf("%s<li>%s</li>\n", $padding, $entry[1]);

        if ($sub = build_tree($data, $entry[0], $indent+4))
            $out .= sprintf("%s<ul>\n%s%s</ul>\n", $padding, $sub, $padding);
    }
    return $out;
}

print build_tree($data);
```

The above will print

```
<li>Categoria 1</li>
<ul>
    <li>Categoria 1.1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Categoria 1.1.2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Categoria 1.2</li>
    <li>Categoria 1.3</li>
</ul>
<li>Categoria 2</li>
<li>Categoria 3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is adopted/not tested version of my options hierarchy (if answer to both my questions is yes):

```
function GetOptions($parentSection,$level)
  { 
    $result = mysql_query('select category_id,category_name,category_parent from categories AS names where (category_parent='.$parentSection.') ORDER BY category_id;');
    $level_prefix=str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;',$level);
    if($result)
    {   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {  
                $sec .= '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$level_prefix.$star.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
                 GetOptions($row['category_id'],$level+1*2);}
        }
    }
    return $sec; $sec = '';
  }
```

and you call it as (don't forget SELECT tag if you use Options):

```
echo GetOptions(0,0);
```

Comment: It's very inefficient to perform so many queries to your database when it can all be fetched with just one query. `$sec = '';` will never be executed as the function terminates after the `return` statement. PHP usually uses the C naming convention, yours look more like C#.

Comment: as it says above - adopted version. and the question you rise is forever there - in ideal world we would like to have once big query for everything we use in our script. but in the real world - we just go with a simpler solution. modern technology allow us to have multiple queries without much difference between big and multiple queries (in terms of rendering, if i had echo above- this would be quicker) for several years now...

Comment: oh yeah - $sec = ''; - was pasting mistake. didn't check where i pasted to... my fault - should be at the top

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but think it should be something like this atleast

```
function PrintRecursive($sql, $id = 0){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT category_id,category_name,category_parent FROM categories WHERE category_parent = {$id}", $sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['category_id'] ." | ". $row['category_name'] ." | ". $row['category_parent'] ."<br/>";
        PrintRecursive($sql, $row['category_parent']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well since you said you want the results of a specific category.

Say the $category_id is 1

```
    function Subcats($category_id){
        $getsubcats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_parent = $category_id");
$sub_cats = mysql_num_rows($getsubcats);

    if($sub_cats == 0){
    echo "There are no sub categories for this category";
    }

    else {

        while($rowsubcats = mysql_fetch_array($getsubcats)){

        $sub_cat_id = $rowsubcats['id'];
        $sub_cat_name = $rowsubcats['name'];
        // other row info

        echo "write what you want to display here<BR>";
        } // end loop for each sub cat
    } // end if subcats > 0
}
```